# Nodejs serialport data.toString() Failing encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I've got a barcode scanner hooked up to a raspberry pi running nodejs serialport. The serialport instance is listening to `/dev/input/event0`

When I run this

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SP = serialport.SerialPort;
var port = "/dev/input/event0"
var sp = new SP(port);


sp.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log( data);
});
```

I git a blob of Buffer objects from a scan. (I think it counts each number in the code as a data event.

My problem is, I can't even get it to converto to proper utf8 numbers. How can I get the data decoded?

Update-1: This is the result of the raw `console.log(data)` after scanning a barcode with the numbers `19024336`

```
<Buffer 32 a9 3b 51 54 76 0c 00 04 00 04 00 1e 00 07 00 32 a9 3b 51 6d 76 0c 00 01 00 02 00 01 00 00 00 32 a9 3b 51 76 76 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer 32 a9 3b 51 c6 8d 0c 00 04 00 04 00 1e 00 07 00 32 a9 3b 51 dc 8d 0c 00 01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 32 a9 3b 51 e2 8d 0c 00 04 00 04 00 26 00 07 00 32 a9 3b ...>
<Buffer 32 a9 3b 51 61 cc 0c 00 04 00 04 00 1f 00 07 00 32 a9 3b 51 78 cc 0c 00 01 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 32 a9 3b 51 7e cc 0c 00 04 00 04 00 21 00 07 00 32 a9 3b ...>
<Buffer 32 a9 3b 51 5f fb 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 a9 3b 51 e4 0a 0d 00 04 00 04 00 20 00 07 00 32 a9 3b 51 fc 0a 0d 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 32 a9 3b ...>
<Buffer 32 a9 3b 51 f6 d5 0d 00 04 00 04 00 28 00 07 00 32 a9 3b 51 0a d6 0d 00 01 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00 32 a9 3b 51 12 d6 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

It returns different results (from what my human eyes can read here) each time I scan

You may also be interested to know that `Buffer.isBuffer(data);` returns true

Comment: Can you show an example of what the `data` Buffer looks like? What does your `console.log` display?

Comment: updated to show you what `console.log` displays

Comment: It doesn't look like the scanner is outputting the numbers as a human-readable value. What kind of scanner are you using? Have you looked at any available documentation to see what the output should be? It looks like it is sending repeated blocks starting with `32a93b51`. Are you sure you have the right baudrate?

Comment: The scanner is a Taotronics http://cl.ly/NSvu and has many available configurations. By default its configured as a keyboard wedge (emulating keyboard behavior) so if I plug it into a regular computer, it just outputs plain text string of numbers with a return at the end. 

I have tried configuring it to be serial output, configuring all the  baudrate, data bits, stop bits, parity etc to match the configuration. But that didnt work either. So I set it back to the keyboard wedge settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at a module like this: https://github.com/Bornholm/node-keyboard

To elaborate though, the answer is that the output of `/dev/input/event0` is not ASCII characters. The output is a series of structs in the format described here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt as `struct input_event`.

For instance, that means given the second chunk of your output

```
32 a9 3b 51 54 76 0c 00 04 00 04 00 1e 00 07 00
```

breaks down like this:

```
// 32-bit int timestamp (1362864434) - Sat, 09 Mar 2013 21:27:14 GMT
32 a9 3b 51 

// microsecond-granularity time
54 76 0c 00

// 16-bit short (1) indicating it is a key event 
01 00

// 16-bit short (2) is the keycode for the key '1'.
02 00

// 32-bit int (1) indicating it was a keypress.
01 00 00 00
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for this. I was able to see the output was not the ASCII I was expecting using `evtest` once I installed it. Then I was looking for something like this keylogger after i stumbled upon https://github.com/nodebits/linux-joystick and was looking into building my own after this pattern. But looks like someone beat me to it. Thanks again